# Sqoop - problems with --options-file parameter

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I created a file called database.txt which content is:

> --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//123.123.123.123:123/database --username user --password pass

And when I try to use it in the sqoop query like follows:

> sqoop import --options-file database.txt --table
>   MyTable --as-avrodatafile --null-string
>   '\N' --null-non-string '\N' --compress --compression-codec
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec --target-dir
>   hdfs:///user/myuser/AvroFiles/table --split-by
>   SRC --enclosed-by '\"' --map-column-java
>   CREATED_DATT=String,UPDATED_DATT=String

I get the following error:

> 17/03/15 11:06:23 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments
>   for import: 17/03/15 11:06:23 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized
>   argument: --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//123.123.123.123:123/database
>   --username user --password pass 17/03/15 11:06:23 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table 17/03/15 11:06:23
>   ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: MyTable 17/03/15
>   11:06:23 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument:
>   --as-avrodatafile ...

However if I write the connection parameters directly everything works fine:

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//123.123.123.123:123/database
>   --username user --password pass --table MyTable --as-avrodatafile --null-string
>   '\N' --null-non-string '\N' --compress --compression-codec
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec --target-dir
>   hdfs:///user/myuser/AvroFiles/table --split-by
>   SRC --enclosed-by '\"' --map-column-java
>   CREATED_DATT=String,UPDATED_DATT=String

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An options file is a text file where **each line** identifies an option in the order that it appears otherwise on the command line.

Modify `database.txt` :

```
--connect
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//123.123.123.123:123/database
--username
user
--password
pass
```

Check sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_options_files_to_pass_arguments) for more details.